# How can I configure OWASP dependency-check on Jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy

How can I transform this XML file to Groovy script in order to configure dependency-check on Jenkins?

This is the XML `org.jenkinsci.plugins.DependencyCheck.DependencyCheckToolBuilder.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<org.jenkinsci.plugins.DependencyCheck.DependencyCheckToolBuilder_-DependencyCheckToolBuilderDescriptor plugin="dependency-check-jenkins-plugin@5.1.1">
  <installations>
    <org.jenkinsci.plugins.DependencyCheck.tools.DependencyCheckInstallation>
      <name>test-dependency-check</name>
      <home></home>
      <properties>
        <hudson.tools.InstallSourceProperty>
          <installers>
            <org.jenkinsci.plugins.DependencyCheck.tools.DependencyCheckInstaller>
              <id>8.2.1</id>
            </org.jenkinsci.plugins.DependencyCheck.tools.DependencyCheckInstaller>
          </installers>
        </hudson.tools.InstallSourceProperty>
      </properties>
    </org.jenkinsci.plugins.DependencyCheck.tools.DependencyCheckInstallation>
  </installations>
</org.jenkinsci.plugins.DependencyCheck.DependencyCheckToolBuilder_-DependencyCheckToolBuilderDescriptor>
```

This is the groovy code.

```
      import hudson.model.*
      import hudson.tools.*
      import jenkins.model.*
      import org.jenkinsci.plugins.DependencyCheck.*

      String name = 'test-dependency-check'
      String id = '8.2.1'

      def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
      def descriptor = instance.getDescriptor(DependencyCheckToolBuilder.DependencyCheckToolBuilderDescriptor.class)
      def installations = descriptor.getInstallations()

      def installation = new DependencyCheckInstallation(name, null)
      def properties = new InstallSourceProperty([new DependencyCheckInstaller(id)])
      installation.setProperties(properties)

      installations.add(installation)
      descriptor.save()
```

And this is the error.

```
"msg": "script failed with stacktrace:\n org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:\nScript1.groovy: 13: unable to resolve class DependencyCheckInstallation \n @ line 13, column 20.\n   def installation = new DependencyCheckInstallation(name, null)\n                      ^\n\nScript1.groovy: 14: unable to resolve class DependencyCheckInstaller \n @ line 14, column 45.\n    = new InstallSourceProperty([new Depend\n                                 ^\n\n2 errors\n\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:958)\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:605)\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:554)\n\tat groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)\n\tat groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)\n\tat groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)\n\tat groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)\n\tat groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:584)\n\tat groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:623)\n\tat groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:594)\n\tat hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$Script.call(RemotingDiagnostics.java:142)\n\tat hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$Script.call(RemotingDiagnostics.java:114)\n\tat hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45)\n\tat hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics.executeGroovy(RemotingDiagnostics.java:111)\n\tat jenkins.model.Jenkins._doScript(Jenkins.java:4516)\n\tat jenkins.model.Jenkins.doScriptText(Jenkins.java:4494)\n\tat java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)\n\tat org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:396)\n\tat org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:408)\n\tat org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:212)\n\tat org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:145)\n\tat org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$11.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:535)\n\tat org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)\n\tat org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:747)\n\tat org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:878)\n\tat org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:676)\n\tat org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:755)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1617)\n\tat hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)\n\tat jenkins.security.ResourceDomainFilter.doFilter(ResourceDomainFilter.java:76)\n\tat hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)\n\tat hudson.plugins.audit_trail.AuditTrailFilter.doFilter(AuditTrailFilter.java:113)\n\tat hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)\n\tat com.atlassian.bitbucket.jenkins.internal.applink.oauth.serviceprovider.auth.OAuth1aRequestFilter.doFilter(OAuth1aRequestFilter.java:91)\n\tat hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)\n\tat net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:239)\n\tat net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:215)\n\tat net.bull.javamelody.PluginMonitoringFilter.doFilter(PluginMonitoringFilter.java:88)\n\tat org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.monitoring.HudsonMonitoringFilter.doFilter(HudsonMonitoringFilter.java:114)\n\tat hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)\n\tat jenkins.telemetry.impl.UserLanguages$AcceptLanguageFilter.doFilter(UserLanguages.java:128)\n\tat hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)\n\tat hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)\n\tat hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:153)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)\n\tat hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)\n\tat hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)\n\tat hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)\n\tat jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)\n\tat hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)\n\tat org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)\n\tat hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)\n\tat org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)\n\tat hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)\n\tat org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)\n\tat hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)\n\tat jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.success(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:139)\n\tat jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:82)\n\tat hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)\n\tat org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)\n\tat hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)\n\tat hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)\n\tat hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)\n\tat hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)\n\tat org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)\n\tat hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)\n\tat org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)\n\tat jenkins.security.SuspiciousRequestFilter.doFilter(SuspiciousRequestFilter.java:36)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:545)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:566)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1610)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1300)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1580)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1215)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)\n", 
    "output": ""
```